# Am I a target of retaliatory downvoting?

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I seem to have made an enemy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/i-seem-to-have-made-an-enemy)

Between nine and eleven minutes ago, someone (or possibly more than one person, although the fact that all of this has happened in such a short time-frame suggests a single perpetrator) has downvoted every single answer that I've given in math.se.

Could a moderator please look into this?

Comment: It would be better if you contacted the moderators at team+math@stackexchange.com about this kind of issue, in the future (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#flagging)). But I've identified the guilty party and they will be dealt with shortly. The lost rep should be returned soon, as Fabian explained the system looks out for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a moderator to look into this, they could not reverse the votes themselves anyway.

Every 24 hours such irregular voting patterns are reversed automatically, there is no further need for intervention as this is completely automated.

Comment: There **is** a need for the moderators to be informed, so that we can deal with the guilty user. Just because the effects go away doesn't mean the person who did it shouldn't suffer some consequences.

Comment: @Zev I assumed that this is a one-time offense, not a repeated pattern from the description of the OP. I don't think that this is already enough for suspending users, and there is not much else a mod could do. I do agree that for repeat offenders there should be some consequences, but I really would not worry about the occasional downvote spree, that is corrected automatically and it is just not worth it having the mods spend a lot of time for dealing with that.

Comment: Maybe math.SE is just lucky so far, but I think we've had very little of this sort of problem, so I don't mind dealing with it; even if I or another mod had ultimately decided that no suspension was necessary, I'd want that to be our decision, instead of having users not report "crimes" because they think it would just bother the "police". But I can imagine that on sites like SO, which have a lot more users and a lot more for the mods to deal with, you would probably be right. As it turns out this user had been a problem in the past, so it was useful to hear about this incident.